# How to auto-restart Mongodb in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord

I can't figure out how to auto-restart mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04 in the event that it crashes due to memory-pressure.

I'm using supervisord for other scripts etc, but mongod is through systemctl and I'm not sure how that ties into it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. Edit your mongod service: `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`
2. Add `Restart=always` under `service`
3. Reload systemctl daemon: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Now whenever mongod gets killed. It'll get respawned by systemctl.

Comment: But how can you persist this when apt updates the service file when mongo updates>

Comment: if you are in aws then you can download it from s3 or somewhere.

Comment: Instead of adding it to the file `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`, create a new file (and folder structure, if needed) at `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/always_restart.conf`. Then add the line `[Service]`, and after it add the one mentioned in the answer i.e `Restart=always`. Run step 3. and it will persists even when apt updates the service file.

Answer (score 3):

When you install `mongoDB` just run `systemctl enable mongod.service` on terminal.

This will make your mongoDB service auto-start on every restart.

Comment: Does this also work if mongodb just crashes? I thought systemctl enable only works for running the service on reboot - not when the service just crashes for whatever reason?

Comment: @DevSanghani No this doesn't work, you are correct. `enable` only makes systemd start the service on boot. This answer is invalid.